# How do I add an activity indicator view to my UITableViewController programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a `UITableViewController` that I need to add an activity indicator view to. I want the activity indicator to animate until the tableview has loaded. I've tried `[self.view addSubview:self.activityIndicator];` but it doesn't appear. What should the activity indicator's parent view be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which part of this solved my problem, but I think it was giving the activity indicator view a frame that fixed it.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
```